# Creating a new table with multiples SUMs from another table

Tags: mysql, sum

I am new at stackoverflow.com, please accept my apologies if my question is dumb. I am also a newbie in MySQL, and now I am trying to create a new table from an existing table. My existing table has 3 columns (Date, Time, Values).

I need to create a new table in which I'll have to sum all the values depending on time. So, in the new table I'll have only two columns (Time, Sum) and 24 rows. In the time column I'll have the hours (00:00, 01:00, 02:00, ... , 22:00, 23:00). In the second column I'll have the sum of all the values from 00:00, all the values from 01:00, ... ,all the values from 22:00, all the values from 23:00).

I can't find the right syntax to do it, and I can't find more ways to search for this. I'm working on this for two days already.

Can you help me, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use group by in order to do this
"Select SUM(values) from table group by time"
(I am not really sure if this is the exact way, but this should hopefully do it)